# How to achieve below design in "MaterialTextView" in android?

Tags: android, textview, material-design, material-components-android, material-components

It is possible to achieve this design in "single MaterialTextView" in android? else what are the ways to achieve(Single Textview)? Please share your suggestions, Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put 3 TextView in a view and give them 1 dp margin for example or a view with 1 dp between them.
and set textalignment center.
set text color white and set for them background.

Comment: It is possible to single text view?

Comment: @RaJ no, you should use at least 3 textView

Comment: Okay, I will do, Thank you.

Comment: @RaJ if it work for you please check the answer as correct answer, thanks.